# Issue: unable to scrape star rating from Tripadvisor

Tags: r

I am scraping de following Tripadvisor page, but I am unable to obtain the star rating.

```
web <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g1905488-d253602-Reviews-Hotel_de_Mar_Gran_Melia-Illetes_Calvia_Majorca_Balearic_Islands.html")
```

I have tried using this code, and tried for different css classes but it still doesn't work. It returns NA.

```
df$Estrellas = web %>%
  html_nodes("#ABOUT_TAB .uq1qMUbD") %>%
  html_attr("alt") %>%
  gsub(" of 5 stars", "", .) %>%
  as.integer()
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone knows where the mistake is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unluckily, you [cannot do that](https://tripadvisor.mediaroom.com/us-terms-of-use).

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks anyway for your notice